# Overwrite a line in a file

Tags: c

I'm trying to overwrite a line in a file that contains only unsigned long numbers.
The contents of the file look like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I want to replace a specific number with the number 0. The code I wrote looks like this:

```
FILE *f = fopen("timestamps", "r+");

unsigned long times = 0;
int pos = 0;
while(fscanf(f, "%lu\n", &times) != EOF)
{
    if(times == 3)
    {
        fseek(f, pos, SEEK_SET);
        fprintf(f, "%lu\n", 0);
    }
    times = 0;
    pos = ftell(f);
}
fclose(f);

f = fopen("timestamps", "r");
times = 0;
while(fscanf(f, "%lu\n", &times) != EOF)
{
    printf("%lu\n", times);
    times = 0;
}
fclose(f);
```

The output of the program looks like this:

```
1
2
10
5
```

Interestingly, if I cat the file, it looks like this:

```
1
2
10

5
```

Am I making a mistake in my `ftell`? Also, why didn't the `printf` show the missing line that the `cat` showed?

Comment: Remove the `\n` from the `fscanf`

Comment: @user3666471, it seems to output fine; the only issue I see is that `fprintf(f, "%lu\n", 0);` should use an `int` perhaps `fprintf(f, "%d\n", 0);`

Comment: `long pos = 0;`, `fprintf(f, "%lu\n", 0UL);fflush(f);`

Comment: The problem is that `3` is one character long, while `10` is two character long. The file was `...2\n3\n4\n5...` and now it is `...2\n10\n\n5...` since `3\n4` has been replaced by `10\n`.

Comment: Testing your sournce on my Linux system seems to produce the expected output and the expected file contents. I would guess that you are on a system which has different characters to mark end of line. On such systems, opening the file as a text file might help: fopen(filename, "r+t")

Comment: @francis: but the target was to overwrite a single `3` with a single `0`.

Comment: If you are on a 32-bit system, use %u to print an integer instead of %lu. Concerning missing newline in your output, this is caused by `fscanf`, a single call of your fscanf consumes your number and all blank characters after it (i.e. both newlines). Look into the manual page of scanf.

Comment: (Just a footnote: this is not reproducible under Mac OSX -- not even when saving the `timestamps` as "Windows" text, which means the problem lies in the implementations in your local library. The provided code works "as intended" on my system.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce and fix.

The present problem is that when you open a file in `r+` you **must** call `fseek` at each time you switch from reading to writing and from writing to reading.

Here, you correctly call `fseek` before writing the `0`, but **not** after that write and the following read. The file pointer is not correctly positionned and you get *undefined behaviour*.

Fix is trivial, simply replace :

```
if(times == 3)
{
    fseek(f, pos, SEEK_SET);
    fprintf(f, "%lu\n", 0);
}
```

with

```
if(times == 3)
{
    fseek(f, pos, SEEK_SET);
    fprintf(f, "%lu\n", 0);
    pos = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, pos, SEEK_SET);
}
```

But **BEWARE** : it works here because you replace a line by a line of exactly same length. If you tried to replace a line containing 1000 with a line containing 0 you would get an extra line containing `0` on a windows system where end of line is `\r\n` and `00` on an unix like system with end of line `\n`.

Because here is what would happen (Windows case) :

Before rewrite :

```
...  1  0  0  0 \r \n ...
```

After :

```
...  0 \r \n  0 \r \n ...
```

because a sequential file is ... a sequential serie of byte !

Comment: At this point, I think it's better to open a new file and and do the changes I want over there. Makes changes "in place" in a file is a big can of worms.

Comment: @user3666471 Yes ! The only use case for in place replacement is for (normally binary) files that have fixed length records and for which you can do random acces.

Answer (score 0):

The most comfortable way (in my opinion) to change text files is to create a new temporary file, copy the old one, line by line, with whatever changes you need, delete the old (or rename) and rename the temporary file.

Something like

```
char line[1000];
FILE *original, *temporar;
original = fopen("original", "r");
temporar = fopen("temporar", "w");
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, original)) {
    processline(line);
    fprintf(temporar, "%s", line);
}
fclose(temporar);
fclose(original);
unlink("original"); // or rename("original", "original.bak");
rename("temporar", "original");
```

Of course you need to validate all calls in real code.